# Javascript download zip file from server

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a zip file in a predefined location on my web application server. 
I'm trying to download the file using Javascript and i can get the following to work in FF but not in Chrome. 
Has anyone come across a better way to do this that is cross browser friendly way (FF/Chrome/IE)? If i could force the Save as prompt even better. Im using the dojo toolkit if it helps

```
function downloadZip() {

    var a = document.createElement("a");

    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.href     = "/path_to_file/my.zip";

    a.click();
}
```

Comment: Why not just `window.location.href = '/path_to_file/my.zip'`?

Comment: so was thinking of this but i dont have any way of getting the context of the web application at this point... (that i know of)

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
function downloadURI(uri, name) 
{
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    link.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used `dojo/request/iframe` for this. This is my exact code:

```
iframe._currentDfd = null; // Force Dfd to be empty in case prior calls have not been cleared
iframe.post('path_to_file/file.zip',{
            data: params,
            handleAs: "html"
            }).then(function (data) {
                 console.log('Then called' + data);
            }, function (err) {
                 console.log(err);
});
```

This works in Chrome, Firefox and IE.